# How to Make Inputs in Bootstrap Smaller in Size?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have tried to add an input for users to insert their emails for subscribing to my newsletter.But  the  text  box  is  extending from  end to end of the div. I want to make it smaller. I have used the following code.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:gray;">

<h2 class="fw-bold text-center">Subscribe to Our Newsletter</h2>
<p class="fw-bold text-center">Stay Updated With Our Offers & News</p>

<form>


<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newsletter" placeholder="Enter Your Email" >
  <span class="input-group-text" id="newsletterbutton"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Go </button></span>
</div>

</form>


</div>
```

Comment: set property width for style css

Answer (score 0):

you have Several methods
you can use col-4 for parent of form
you can use width for your form
and you can use margin from x and if you use

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).